# What's the recommended / fastest way to read xml from a POST to an http servlet?

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I've been trying to find a 'reference' example for the fastest / accepted way to read xml input from a http servlet, but can't seem to find a definitive answer.

Here's the context:  we have an application, which is 12 years old, which works just fine in production, but I want to see if we're missing a trick and could make it faster.

It takes post requests consisting of xml (see the bottom of the post for schema and sample xml), and marshalls it to a java object using JAXB 1.0, then finds a request processor depending on request id, which then handles the request and writes the response.

I'm a bit suspicious about the number of String operations, and I think maybe we should be using more buffered readers / writers, maybe a Scanner, and any other 'new' (ie more recent than java 1.2...) features.

Here's a rough summary of how the requests are currently processed:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
    InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( is ); 
    char[] buffer = new char[4096]; 
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); 
    int bytes_read; 
    try
    {    //manual bufferering - can't we just use request.getReader() ?
        while ((bytes_read = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
            writer.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read); 
        } 
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to read the inputstream.  Please try again.");
    }

    String xml = writer.toString();
    //now we look for the payload and extract it:
    String tag = "payload";
    String header = null;
 String body = null;
 String innerPayload = null;
 String footer = null;
  int start = xml.indexOf("<" + tag);
    if(start < 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("Start tag \"" + tag + "\" was not found in the xml.");

    int end = xml.indexOf("</" + tag + ">");
    if(end < 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("End tag \"" + tag + "\" was not found in the xml.");

    int closeStart = xml.indexOf(">", start);
    int closeEnd = xml.indexOf(">", end);

    if(xml.charAt(closeStart - 1)=='/')
    {
        body = xml.substring(start,  closeStart + 1);
        innerPayload = null;
        header = xml.substring(0, closeStart + 1);
        footer = xml.substring(closeStart + 1, xml.length());
    }
    else
    {
        body = xml.substring(start, closeEnd + 1);
        innerPayload = xml.substring(closeStart + 1, end);
        header = xml.substring(0, closeStart + 1);
        footer = xml.substring(end, xml.length());
    }
FsRequest envelope;     
Object xml = JAXBRequestHelper.bind(header + footer);

        if(xml instanceof FsRequest)
            envelope = (FsRequest) xml;
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid XML request.");
Object payloadType = JAXBRequestHelper.bind(innerPayload);
//because the payload type is xs:any, I don't think we can avoid a cast here
//in this case, it's a purchase:
Purchase purchase = (Purchase) payloadType
//request processor then handles the purchase using purchase.getMsisdn(), etc
```

A sample xml request might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <fs-request id="100004"purchase_locale="en_GB">
  <payload>
   <purchase>
    <msisdn>13435456456</msisdn>
    <package-id>package123</package-id>
   </purchase>
  </payload>
</fs-request>
```

The definition of the xsd is a bit special, too. 'payload' is defined as xs:any which makes marshalling more tricky:

```
 <xs:element name="fs-request">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="payload" type="common:payloadType" minOccurs="0"/>    
        </xs:sequence>


<xs:complexType name="payloadType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Is it just me or is this code a bit messy?  If so, is there an obvious way to make it cleaner / faster?  I'd love to see a reference example (although the xs:any payload type makes things a bit more complicated).

Comment: I think `SAX` is the best choice.

Comment: If you are marshalling into a Java object I would have thought that JAXB is probably faster than anything you can write yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a `JAX-RS` framework like [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net)

Doing the serialization job manually is usually overkill.

Answer (score 1):

If you desire speed increase you can take a look at [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) (Simple API for XML) of [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX) (Streaming API for XML). They does not require to load whole file in a memory to parse it like DOM parsers.

But using them is tedious (espesially SAX). I would recommend to check first more easy-to-use library like [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding) (Java Architecture for XML Binding). JAXB can have acceptable speed for your task, while giving greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to do it the manual way using standard JRE libs, this is the way to do it.

You have to think about potential XML threats though.

```
@Override
public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{
        HttpServletRequest hReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if (hReq.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST") && hReq.getContentType().equals("text/xml")){
            // 1. Create XML doc from input         
            logger.debug("1. create XML content from input");
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(hReq.getInputStream());
            // 2. Do your stuff with the Doc e.g. use doc.getDocumentElement()));

        } else {
            HttpServletResponse hResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            // Only HTTP POST is supported
            hResponse.sendError(500, "Unsupported");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.fatal(e,e);
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}
```